# In Year One/in Grade one

Tags: word-choice

When talking about school can either of the four options be used in my sentence?
I moved house when I was in Year/Grade One...

1."In Year/Grade One".

2."In Year/Grade 1".

3."In year/grade one".

4."In the first year/grade."

Should I capitalize year, grade and one/1?

Comment: Many people will say that you can't have 'either of' more than two options. A particular country's local school system may use 'grade', 'year', 'standard', etc for the stages of school, and only that term will be appropriate. Also capitalisation may be a local convention.

Comment: I agree with Micheal’s comment. It depends on the school system since a lot of systems call ‘years’ different things.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, so they are correct as they are written,  aren't they?

Comment: Each may or may not be correct, depending on the school, country, etc.

Comment: The head teacher may write in a formal letter or bulletin 'All Year Six students must wear hats on Tuesdays' and a student may send a text to his friend saying 'The head says year 6 kids must wear hats'.